# Rust: How to fix borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I have simple client/server application. I am receiving message on the server side from client but I want to send that response to the channel from server to other file and I am receiving error  "borrowed value does not live long enough".

I have searched in the stack overflow for similar previous questions but not getting enough understanding of lifetime. Is there a good documentation    or if simple example available on this topic?

For now if someone can help me to fix this code (may be edit the portion of code which needs to fix) that would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

## Server side:

```
use std::os::unix::net::UnixDatagram;
use std::path::Path;

fn unlink_socket (path: impl AsRef<Path>) {
    let path = path.as_ref();
    if Path::new(path).exists() {
        let result = std::fs::remove_file(path);
        match result {
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Couldn't remove the file: {:?}", e);
            },
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}

pub fn tcp_datagram_server() {
    pub static FILE_PATH: &'static str = "/tmp/datagram.sock";
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];
    unlink_socket(FILE_PATH);
    let socket = match UnixDatagram::bind(FILE_PATH) {
        Ok(socket) => socket,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't bind: {:?}", e);
            return;
        }
    };
    println!("Waiting for client to connect...");
    loop {
        let received_bytes = socket.recv(buf.as_mut_slice()).expect("recv function failed");
        println!("Received {:?}", received_bytes);
        let received_message = from_utf8(buf.as_slice()).expect("utf-8 convert failed");
        tx.clone().send(received_message);
    }
}

fn main() {
   tcp_datagram_server();
}
```

## client side:

```
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::os::unix::net::UnixDatagram;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::prelude::*;

pub fn tcp_datagram_client() {
    pub static FILE_PATH: &'static str = "/tmp/datagram.sock";
    let socket = UnixDatagram::unbound().unwrap();
    match socket.connect(FILE_PATH) {
        Ok(socket) => socket,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect: {:?}", e);
            return;
        }
    };
    println!("TCP client Connected to TCP Server {:?}", socket);
    loop {
        socket.send(b"Hello from client to server").expect("recv function failed");
    }
}

fn main() {
   tcp_datagram_client();
}
```

Error I am getting

```
error[E0597]: `buf` does not live long enough
  --> src/unix_datagram_server.rs:38:42
   |
38 |         let received_message = from_utf8(buf.as_slice()).expect("utf-8 convert failed");
   |                                          ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
41 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `buf` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `tx` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `std::sync::mpsc::Sender`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined

error: aborting due to previous error; 8 warnings emitted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For now if someone can help me to fix this code (may be edit the portion of code which needs to fix) that would be helpful.

Well the message seems rather clear. `send` does exactly what it says it does, it *sends* the parameter through the channel. This means the data must live long enough and remain valid "forever" (it needs to be alive and valid in the channel, as well as when fetched from it by the receiver).

That is not the case here. rustc can't understand that the function never returns, and it can panic anyway which will end up the same: the function will terminate, which will invalidate `buf`. Since `received_message` borrows `buf`, that means `received_message` can't be valid after the function has terminated. But at that point the message would still be in the channel waiting to be read (or retrieved by the receiver doing who knows what).

Therefore your construction is not allowed.

A second issue is that you're overwriting the buffer data on every loop, which has the same effect of breaking the message you sent during the previous iteration, and thus is not correct either. Though Rust won't let you do that either: if you work around the first error it will tell you that there's an outstanding shared borrow (the message sent through the channel) so you can't modify the backing buffer in the following iteration.

The solution is quite simple: have each iteration create an *owned* string (copying the current iteration's message) and send that through the channel:

```
tx.clone().send(received_message.to_string());
```

Also, these are more style / inefficiency remarks but:

- The `clone()` on `tx` is completely redundant. The point of having a sender that is `Clone` is being able to send from multiple threads (hence *mp* in the channel name, that's for *multiple producers*). Here you have a single thread, the original sender works fine.
- `.as_slice()` and `.as_mut_slice()` are rarely used unless necessary, which they aren't here: array references coerce to slices, so you can just use `&mut buf` and `&buf`. And why are you calling `Path::new` on something that's already a path? It doesn't do anything but it's not useful either.
- It is rather annoying that your snippet is missing multiple imports and thus doesn't even compile as is.
- From more of a unixy perspective, errors are usually printed on stderr. In Rust, `eprintln` does that for you (otherwise working in the same way `println` does). And I don't understand the purpose of marking a lexically nested `static` `pub`. Since the `static` is inside the function it's not even visible to the function's siblings, to say nothing of external callers. As a result I'd end up with this:

  ```rust
  use std::os::unix::net::UnixDatagram;
  use std::path::Path;
  use std::sync::mpsc;
  use std::str::from_utf8;

  fn unlink_socket (path: impl AsRef<Path>) {
      let path = path.as_ref();
      if path.exists() {
          if let Err(e) = std::fs::remove_file(path) {
              eprintln!("Couldn't remove the file: {:?}", e);
          }
      }
  }

  static FILE_PATH: &'static str = "/tmp/datagram.sock";
  pub fn tcp_datagram_server() {
      unlink_socket(FILE_PATH);
      let socket = match UnixDatagram::bind(FILE_PATH) {
          Ok(socket) => socket,
          Err(e) => {
              eprintln!("Couldn't bind: {:?}", e);
              return;
          }
      };

      let (tx, _) = mpsc::channel();
      let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];
      println!("Waiting for client to connect...");
      loop {
          let received_bytes = socket.recv(&mut buf).expect("recv function failed");
          println!("Received {:?}", received_bytes);
          let received_message = from_utf8(&buf).expect("utf-8 convert failed");
          tx.send(received_message.to_string());
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are made in good faith, but there ARE cases (admittedly rare) where a value will never go out of scope because your function is meant to last forever, and Rust's borrow checker cannot be worked around in that case because Rust's references aren't pointers.

If you think about your code logistically **and are absolutely sure that this is the case**, then - at your own risk - you can cast your pointer as a raw pointer.

`buf.as_slice() as *const u8`

If it's something that has methods you need to use, you will need to cast it back to a reference to use them, e.g.

```
let st = unsafe {
    st.as_mut().expect("invalid state") // we panic here because if this is actually reached then the program can't run anyways and we have bigger problems
};
```