# Rust loop - borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust, zeromq, rust-tokio

In a rebroadcaster (redis to zmq) implementation i am unable to figure out how to resolve the lifetime issue of temporary values (derived from consumed message from pubsub in a loop).

I pretty much understand why, but i am so far failing to produce `Vec<&String>` that i need to pass into zmq publisher. I tried with different types, cloning etc. but i'm just getting same or similar errors related to ownership and lifetime.

The problematic code:

```
async fn ps_rebroadcaster() -> Result<(), ApiError>{

    let mut inproc_publisher: async_zmq::Publish<std::vec::IntoIter<&std::string::String>, &std::string::String>  = async_zmq::publish("ipc://pricing")?.bind()?;
    
    let con_str = &APP_CONFIG.REDIS_URL;
    let conn = create_client(con_str.to_string())
        .await
        .expect("Can't connect to redis");
    let mut pubsub = conn.get_async_connection().await?.into_pubsub();
    match pubsub.psubscribe("T1050_*").await {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(_) => {}
    };

    let mut msg_stream = pubsub.into_on_message();
     
    loop {
        let result = msg_stream.next().await;
        match result {
            Some(message) => {
                 
                let channel_name = message.get_channel_name().to_string();
                let payload_value: redis::Value = message.get_payload().expect("Can't get payload of message");
                let payload_string: String = FromRedisValue::from_redis_value(&payload_value).expect("Can't convert from Redis value");
                
                let item: Vec<&String> = vec![&channel_name , &payload_string  ];
                // problem here  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

                inproc_publisher.send(item.into()).await?;
            }
            None => {
                println!("None received");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

And the error:

```
error[E0597]: `channel_name` does not live long enough
   --> src/server.rs:248:47
    |
248 |                 let item: Vec<&String> = vec![&channel_name , &payload_string  ];
    |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
249 |                 
250 |                 inproc_publisher.send(item.into()).await?;
    |                 ---------------------------------- borrow later used here
251 |             }
    |             - `channel_name` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `payload_string` does not live long enough
   --> src/server.rs:248:63
    |
248 |                 let item: Vec<&String> = vec![&channel_name , &payload_string  ];
    |                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
249 |                 
250 |                 inproc_publisher.send(item.into()).await?;
    |                 ---------------------------------- borrow later used here
251 |             }
    |             - `payload_string` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust: How to fix borrowed value does not live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897874/rust-how-to-fix-borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't answer my problem,  async_zmq::Message - which is what my vector will be converted into - doesn't implement trait `From<std::string::String>>`..   The closest i could use is `From<&'a std::string::String>>` or  `From<&'a str>>` , but i can't figure out how

Comment: It does implement `From<Vec<u8>>` though, so you can use `your_string.into_bytes()` to perform that conversion, which is zero-copy -- the string's allocation is stolen and given to the new vector.

Comment: @cdhowie i can't believe i missed that, it indeed implements From<Vec<u8>> and your solution works - if you post it as an answer, i'll gladly accept it!  Thanks a lot for your quick help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fails because the sink wants an `Into<Message>` but doesn't apparently perform the conversion immediately, so the reference needs to continue to exist for some unspecified amount of time, and the values they refer to are destroyed too soon.  Basically, you need to give the sink an owned value instead of a borrowed one.

You can do this by converting the `String`s into `Message` values before giving them to the `Publish` sink, or by giving it an owned value that can be converted to `Message`.  There isn't a conversion from `String` to `Message`, but there is one from `Vec<u8>`, and you can convert a `String` to a `Vec<u8>` without any copying by using the [`String::into_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes) method.

Comment: I'd love to know why the problem exists in the first place. Is it because ZMQ is written in some other language, and Rust doesn't have visibility of the scope inside ZMQ, and so cannot determine the proper lifetime of the borrowed items? Or have I got that completely wrong?! Thank you :-)

Comment: @bazza Conceptually, the message queue does not need to send the message immediately. Sending a message is asynchronous; you hand off the data, then the message gets sent some time later (or never gets sent if there are networking issues that don't get resolved before the process terminates). The queue needs to therefore own the message data so that it can be guaranteed to live until the message is sent.

Comment: Many thanks @cdhowie. I'm very familiar with ZMQ, but haven't yet really launched off into the realms of Rust, so I don't know anything at all about ZMQ in Rust and the implementation of it that is used. I had visions of the C lib version being used with a weaker expression of ownership requirements, but it sounds like the ZMQ implementation (or wrapper for the ZMQ C library) does it properly. Which is good news :-)